# Manually creating windows phone wallet mswallet package

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Anyone successfully create an .mswallet package for Windows Phone?  I have followed these steps:

1. Downloaded one of the samples
2. Modified the mail file WalletItem.xml
3. Zipped it using 7-zip.
4. Renamed the extension to .mswallet
5. Emailed file to myself and
6. Attempted to import it to my Windows 8.1 phone and received error 82AD0005.

Anyone created such a package?

Comment: I've have a [web service](https://sj2wp.azurewebsites.net/) that creates mswallet files. I just zip the content and choose the mswallet extension. Are you sure you didnt break the XML?

Comment: All I did was download the BlueYonder example, unzipped it using 7zip,  changed the DisplayName in WalletItemxml, zipped the folder BlueYonder  again and renamed the extension from .zip to .mswallet.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder, what software are you using to zip the content?

Comment: I've been using PHPs ZipArchive and 7zip. Did some tests just now and I have no issues modifying the BlueYonder example and zipping it with 7zip and then putting it on my phone. Have you modified 7zips settings? I just right click and click "Zip to xxx".

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder BTW your service produces a 404 when used with Windows 10 Mobile (or maybe always?). Can you check it. There are no mswallet examples out there on MSDN anymore, only broken links. So it would be helpful to get a file from you.

Comment: @eckes yeah the service doesn't work anymore since its 3rd party data source has been discontinued. I'll check what I got left from that project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and same error-numer. Appeared that I've changed the name of the XML file. It must be named: WalletItem.xml and then everything went fine.

Comment: can you please elaborate?